# объект не найден ядром базы данных microsoft office access. C# Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, ms-access

Нужно импортировать данные из excel файла в datagridview, но он не может найти файл, хотя путь указал правильно. Выдает ошибку : объект не найден ядром базы данных microsoft office access. Где ошибка? Заранее спасибо
Сам excel [http://imgur.com/W0ENhDF](https://imgur.com/W0ENhDF)

```
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Connection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            MessageBox.Show(path.ToString());
            path = Path.Combine(path, "textfortest.xlsx");
            string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+path+@"; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRowsIMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0""";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            string Strcmd = "select * from [Лист1$A1:D9]";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Strcmd, conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                ds.Clear();
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: прикрепите трейс

Comment: @SeniorAutomator что это такое? Еще нет опыта)

Comment: stack trace-  исключение, которое выдает программа

Answer (score 1):

Сообщение об ошибке при выполнении запроса на объединение, содержащего более одного объединения для таблиц со сложными данными: "Объект не найден ядром базы данных Microsoft Office Access"

При добавлении поля вложения в таблицу может отображаться следующее сообщение об ошибке:
{
Объект не найден ядром базы данных Microsoft Office Access. 
Проверьте существование объекта и правильность имени и пути.
}
Эта ошибка возникает, когда в поле находится запрос на объединение, содержащий более одного объединения для таблиц со сложными данными.

Взята [отсюда](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/942378)

p.s. думаю, что проблема в названиях колонок похоже

Comment: названиях колонок в excel файле?

Comment: @DmitryUshkevich да, в названиях колонок есть пробелы ?

Comment: проверил на наличие пробелов, пробелов нет. Самый обычный файл, до 5 колоннок 
http://imgur.com/W0ENhDF

Comment: @DmitryUshkevich посмотрите ответ  в этом вопросе http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951005/error-reading-from-excel-in-c-could-not-find-the-object 

Попробуйте сделать также

Comment: большое спасибо, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: с доступом к файлу разобрался(вроде как), теперь  conn.Open(); проходит хорошо(файл видит в той директории), но вот уже через 2 строчки на моменте заполнения.  adapter.Fill(ds);
ошибка объект [Лист1 $A1:D9] не найден ядром базы данных microsoft office access.

Comment: @DmitryUshkevich похоже вы адрес ячейки указываете не правильно, должно быть [Лист1!$A1:D9]. `!` пропустили, посмотрите в самом excel как адресуются ячейки с других страниц.